# EndpointNotFoundException and Async Calls

Tags: wcf

Is it possible to catch an EndpointNotFoundException when calling an asynchronous method in WCF?  I've wrapped the service call on my client in a try / catch block, and am catching EndpointNotFoundExceptions, FaultExceptions and general Exceptions, but if the service disappears once the client is running, no exception is caught on the async call, but eventually a timeout occurs.

What is the best way (or is there a way) to quickly catch a dead service during an async call?

Comment: Is this a similar question? (unfortuneatly not yet solved) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1204534

Comment: It is similar, but SO's search didn't find it for me.  Different keywords, obviously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been open a while now with no action.  I guess the answer basically is to set your timeout as low as possible given the network type / amount of processing expected / etc.  One possibility is to set up one endpoint with a very short timeout (eg 5 seconds) with just a 'Ping' method as a heartbeat.  Use the client to call and monitor this method periodically to get the health of the server / endpoint.  As Simon Fox pointed out, check [Where to trap failed connection on WCF calling class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1204534) for a more detailed response.

Answer (score 0):

I am also trying to handle these errors in a manageable way. Here's another thread that is about this subject.

[WCF/C# Unable to catch EndpointNotFoundException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2458631/wcf-c-unable-to-catch-endpointnotfoundexception)