# How to recreate a WCF Service as Singleton instance with SimpleInjector (using Tridion)

Tags: c#, wcf, ioc-container, simple-injector, tridion-core-services

I'm using the IoC Container `SimpleInjector`.
I know that Singletons shouldn't be recreated since that's not their purpose but my problem is with WCF and when it enters into **Faulted** state which according to several readings it cannot be recovered and a new instance needs to be created.

I have a class named `CoreServiceService` which uses two WCF Services.

1. `CoreService`
2. `ECLService`

I want those services to be singleton since I'll be making lots of calls to `CoreServiceSession` and creating those WCF Service is too expensive and takes a lot of times, after the creation, they are much faster.

I'm registering them like this:

```
container.Register(() => new SessionAwareEclServiceClient(binding, eclServiceRemoteAddress), Lifestyle.Singleton);

container.Register(() => new SessionAwareCoreServiceClient(binding, coreServiceRemoteAddress), Lifestyle.Singleton);

container.Register(typeof(ICoreServiceSession), typeof(CoreServiceSession), Lifestyle.Scoped);
```

My problem is that while using `ECLService` if something cannot be retrieved is enters into **Faulted** connection, In that case, I call `.Abort()` and close the connection. But the next time I call my service `ECLService` WCF service keeps being in the `Faulted` state (since it's a singleton) so I need a way to recreate the connection.

I tried with something like:

```
coreServiceSession.EclServiceClient = (SessionAwareEclServiceClient)container.GetInstance(typeof(SessionAwareEclServiceClient));
```

But, of course, it gives me the same instance.

I also tried using this initializer:

```
container.RegisterInitializer<ICoreServiceSession>(coreServiceSession =>
{
    if (coreServiceSession.EclServiceClient.State == CommunicationState.Faulted)
    {
        coreServiceSession.EclServiceClient.Abort();
        coreServiceSession.EclServiceClient = null;
        coreServiceSession.EclServiceClient = (SessionAwareEclServiceClient)container.GetInstance(typeof(SessionAwareEclServiceClient));
    }
}
```

Same thing and I tried to use instead of container.GetInstance, this:

```
coreServiceSession.EclServiceClient = new SessionAwareEclServiceClient(binding, eclServiceRemoteAddress);
```

Same things. Any ideas/options?

It there any way to force to get a new instance in this case?

**UPDATE**

This is part of the class `CoreServiceSession`:

```
public class CoreServiceSession : ICoreServiceSession
{
    public CoreServiceSession(ISessionAwareCoreService sessionAwareEclServiceClient, SessionAwareCoreServiceClient sessionAwareCoreServiceClient)
    {
        EclServiceClient = sessionAwareEclServiceClient;
        CoreServiceClient = sessionAwareCoreServiceClient;
    }

    public ISessionAwareCoreService EclServiceClient { get; set; }

    public SessionAwareCoreServiceClient CoreServiceClient { get; set; }

    public string CreateOrGetStubUris(string eclItemUri)
    {
        var stubInfo = EclServiceClient.CreateOrGetStubUris(new List<string> { eclItemUri }).FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance. Guillermo

Comment: Can you add a method to your instance to force a an update/refresh of some sort?  Can you share your client code?

Comment: @StinkyTowel Added part of the code

Comment: Can you add the code that creates the concrete client of **ISessionAwareCoreService sessionAwareEclServiceClient**?

Comment: That's created by the IoC Container

Comment: [Here's an interesting post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1681787/wcf-client-proxy-initialization/1682038#1682038). To summarize - it says make the `ChannelFactory` a singleton, because that's the expensive part. But don't make the client a singleton.

Answer (score 1):

@ScottHannen already gave the answer in his comment: do not register channels as singletons: they are not expensive to create, only the channel factories are.

As a matter of fact, you shouldn't inject your WCF client objects into constructors at all. Injecting them into a constructor implies that they are a useful abstraction that can be used to intercept, mock or replace, while the class using such client is typically strongly coupled to WCF.

So instead of injecting them into a constructor, let the consumer create them internally using the `ChannelFactory`. Even such `ChannelFactory` typically doesn't have to be injected, you can just new it up in a private static field.

This is how your `CoreServiceSession` might look like:

```
public class CoreServiceSession : ICoreServiceSession
{
    private static readonly ChannelFactory factory =
        new ChannelFactory<ISessionAwareCoreService>(myBinding, myEndpoint);

    public string CreateOrGetStubUris(string eclItemUri)
    {
        var client = factory.CreateChannel();

        try
        {
            return EclServiceClient.CreateOrGetStubUris(
                new List<string> { eclItemUri }).FirstOrDefault();
        }
        finally
        {
            try
            {
                ((IDisposable)client).Dispose();
            }
            catch
            {
                // We need to swallow exceptions thrown by Dispose. 
                // See: https://marcgravell.blogspot.com/2008/11/dontdontuse-using.html
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I second this approach and have used it successfully many times. However, keeping in the spirit of IoC, what I've usually done is inject a Func<ISessionAwareCoreService>() which is registered with the IoC and that lambda takes care of using a singleton ChannelFactory. 

Also extension methods can be written to do a CleanClose of the client (the part in the Try-Finally block